# How to make a blinking text option

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

```
Builder.load_string("""
<ScreenOne>:
    FloatLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        canvas:
            Rectangle:
                source: 'back1.jpg'
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            background_color: 0, 0, 0, 0
            on_press:
                # You can define the duration of the change
                # and the direction of the slide
                root.manager.transition.direction = 'up'
                root.manager.transition.duration = 1
                root.manager.current = 'screen_two'
                App.blink_animation(blinky)   
    BoxLayout: 

# So over here I tried to create a variable 'alpha' for the opacity,
# that I try to change using animation below.

        Label:
            id: blinky
            text: "Click Anywhere To Continue"
            font_size: '20sp'
            font_name: "Raleway-Regular"
            size_hint: (1.0, 0)
            alpha: 1 
            color: (1, 1, 1, self.alpha)


<ScreenTwo>:
    FloatLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        canvas:
            Rectangle:
                source: 'back2.jpg'
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            background_color: 0, 0, 0, 0
            on_press:
                root.manager.transition.direction = 'down'
                root.manager.current = 'screen_one'
""")

# Create a class for all screens in which you can include
# helpful methods specific to that screen

Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', '0') #0 being off 1 being on as in true/false
Config.set('graphics', 'width', '960')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '720')

class ScreenOne(Screen):
    pass

class ScreenTwo(Screen):
    pass


# The ScreenManager controls moving between screens
screen_manager = ScreenManager()

# Add the screens to the manager and then supply a name
# that is used to switch screens
screen_manager.add_widget(ScreenOne(name="screen_one"))
screen_manager.add_widget(ScreenTwo(name="screen_two"))

class KivyTut2App(App):
    def blink_animation(self, blinky, *args):
        anim = Animation(alpha=0, duration=0.5) + Animation(alpha=0, duration=0.5)
        anim += Animation(alpha=1, duration=0.5) + Animation(alpha=1, duration=0.5)
        anim.repeat = True
        anim.start(blinky)
    def build(self):
        return screen_manager

sample_app = KivyTut2App()
sample_app.run()
```

In the first block quote selected above, I try to create the parameter self.alpha, and in the second block quote selected from above, I try to use self.alpha to change opacity and create the animation. The output is just the text without the animation, and I would like to learn where I went wrong.

Comment: I have attempted to edit your post to make sense of the code, but I'm not sure I succeeded. Is the `blinky` `Label` part of `ScreenOne`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that your code should mostly work, however, there are some problems. If the `blinky` `Label` is part of `ScreenOne`, then you won't see the blinking because clicking the `Button` that starts the blinking also switches to `ScreenTwo`. Clicking the `Button` on `ScreenTwo` returns to `ScreenOne` and the blinking should be seen.

If `blinky` is part of `ScreenTwo`, then the `blinky` `id` is not valid within `ScreenOne`.

If you want the blinking to start without clicking the `Button`, then call the `blink_animation()` method from the `build()` method using `Clock.schedule_once()`. First, remove the call to `blink_animation()` from the `Button` `on_press:`, like this:

```
    Button:
        background_color: 0, 0, 0, 0
        on_press:
            # You can define the duration of the change
            # and the direction of the slide
            root.manager.transition.direction = 'up'
            root.manager.transition.duration = 1
            root.manager.current = 'screen_two'
```

Then, call the `blink_animation()` method from the `build()` method and modify the `blink_animation()` method:

```
class KivyTut2App(App):
    def blink_animation(self, dt):
        anim = Animation(alpha=0, duration=0.5) + Animation(alpha=1, duration=0.5)
        anim.repeat = True
        anim.start(screen_manager.get_screen('screen_one').ids.blinky)
    def build(self):
        Clock.schedule_once(self.blink_animation)
        return screen_manager
```